# RegEx: Tag matching

Tags: regex

So I have this tag:

```
^27=10^**370=B10,11**^ 312=7,12,-10,1000 ^368=5,5,10 ^375=B12,2^26=8.0000 ^369=1.0000^5=8.0000^6=9.0000^14=1^15=1^263=1^MVAL=100^NOIA=1
```

I'm trying to match the **11** of the 370=B10,11.

I currently have this:

```
(?<=\^370=B\d\d,)[\d]+
```

which works for this case but the number following the **B** can be 1 or 2 digits and this:

```
(?<=\^370=B\d+,)[\d]+
```

doesn't work because lookbehind requires a fixed width.

Any idea how I can make this robust to work for different combinations: `370=B1,11` and `370=B10,11`

Comment: Where are you using the regex? Show the code. More, why don't you just capture the number?  With `\^370=B\d+,(\d+)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/9ynKUq/1))?

Comment: No particular coding language. The platform accepts broad use regex. The tags are generated text which map to specific fields (B1-15 & 1-12).

Comment: Regex implementations differ one from another, sometimes, greatly. In .NET, your second regex [works fine](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%5e370%3dB%5cd%2b%2c%29%5b%5cd%5d%2b&i=%5e27%3d10%5e370%3dB133330%2c11%5e+312%3d7%2c12%2c-10%2c1000+%5e368%3d5%2c5%2c10+%5e375%3dB12%2c2%5e26%3d8.0000+%5e369%3d1.0000%5e5%3d8.0000%5e6%3d9.0000%5e14%3d1%5e15%3d1%5e263%3d1%5eMVAL%3d100%5eNOIA%3d1). So, *what is YOUR regex flavor*?

Comment: hmm...good question, Will need to find that out.

Comment: Ok, let's try. `\^370=B\d+,\K\d+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a PCRE/Boost/Ongigmo compliant regex like

```php
\^370=B\d+,\K\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9ynKUq/2). *Details*:

- `\^370=B` - `^370=B` text
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `,` - a comma
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `\d+` - one or more digits.